# Access Providers from Dialogs for Flutter hooks

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-hooks, flutter-dialog

I am new to Flutter hooks and riverpod

Basically I have a provider that stores the list of books in a book shelf.

```
class BookList extends StateNotifier<List<BookModel>> {
  BookList() : super([]);

  void setBookList(List<BookModel> bookList) =>
     {state = bookList};
}

final bookListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<BookList>((_) => BookList());
```

Then I have a page which display the books and a create button which will shows the create a new book dialog:

```
class BookShelfPage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final bookList = useProvider(bookListProvider.state);
      
      useEffect(() {
        //API to get list of books
        context.read(bookListProvider).setBookList(//data from API);
      },[]);

      final Function() onCreateBookButtonClicked = () {      
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => ProviderScope(
            child: (new BookCreateDialog())));
      };


      //Data is available for this
      print("book list length 1: " + bookList.length.toString()); 
  }
```

However, I am unable to access the provider values in the dialog:

```
class BookCreateDialog extends HookWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final bookList = useProvider(bookListProvider.state);
      
      //Data is not available for this
      print("book list length 2: " + bookList.length.toString()); 
   }
}
```

Things to note:

1. I have a ProviderScope wrapping my application.
2. I have no problems persist or access the providers across different PAGES or any child widget that resides on the PAGES but I am not able to access the provider values from dialogs.
3. Of course, I can pass the providers' values as parameters to the dialogs but I would like to know if there is any way that I can avoid this as I got a lot values to get from providers.

May I know how to fix this? Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only want to use `ProviderScope` in two cases. The first is wrapping your app as you mentioned. The other case is when using `ScopedProvider`.

What you're essentially doing here:

```dart
builder: (context) => ProviderScope(child: BookCreateDialog());
```

is creating a new scope where the value of your `StateNotifierProvider` is not available (as that value lies within the `ProviderScope` at the root of your app).

Remove that `ProviderScope` and you should get the results you are expecting.